# Select records from single column based on two conditions

Tags: sql, where-clause, between

I might be simple but I need solution.

I have column Id (1 to 10) in my table and I want rows which are having Id between 2 to 4 and 6 to 10, how to retrieve those rows? Anything really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ID BETWEEN 2 and 4
OR ID BETWEEN 6 and 10
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50d36/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE (ID >= 2 and ID <= 4)
OR (ID >= 6 and ID <= 10);
```